# Install Curl in Dev C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Hi I'm trying to install Curl : http://curl.haxx.se/download.html , Dev C++ and so far not achieved, could someone explain how to install Curl in Dev C++?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the details on what you tried and how the installation failed for you?

Comment: Dev C++ is an IDE. You probably need to install cURL first, then tell Dec C++ to look in the install directory, I expect.

Comment: Which dev-c++ version ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First copy `..\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\include` folder from downloaded package into `C:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include` then copy `libraries file (.o,.a,.lib)` that are inside `..\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\lib64` folder into `C:\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib` then compile very first program , don't forget to link `libcurl.a` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

 int main(void)
 {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) 
    {
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
       /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

       /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
       res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
       /* Check for errors */
       if(res != CURLE_OK)
       fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
       curl_easy_strerror(res));

       /* always cleanup */
       curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

I am using `Dev-c++ 5.11 (gcc 4.9.2)` and `curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64`.

Comment: Nice , thanks for the help.if someone fails the code, you have to add the following to the linker dll "libcurldll.a"